# Deezer Javascript SDK track_end event on mobile

Tags: deezer

We've been testing the track_end event which is recently introduced to the Deezer Javascript SDK.

The event seems to be working great on web browsers, however, within the context of Deezer mobile application, as an inapp, the event doesn't seem to firing at all.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The track_end event is not yet available for Deezer AppStudio apps.